# Google Apps Script trigger suddenly firing delayed

Tags: google-apps-script

CLOSED - I have a trigger set in GAS for a precise time, 14:57, to run a function at that point. (that trigger is set up by a function every day afresh)

This worked just fine for many months up until today, but today, the trigger suddenly fired at 15:05, and the function failed because some conditions were not met.

I know why the conditions at 15:05 were not met, that’s not the problem, but why did the trigger suddenly fire with an 8 minute delay today, when it has reliably fired at 14:57 for many months??? I did check the time it was set up for today … 14:57 … so why the delay?

Note that exactly the same trigger is also installed the same way in other, separate spreadsheets and today they fired, as they should, at 14:57.

Very confusing!!!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the function failed because some conditions were not met"? Maybe this is the cause of the delay in the activation time.

Comment: sorry for not being precise: the trigger is set up by a function (1) and the trigger then runs another function (2), when it fires. That function (2) failed because it basically ran with a delay which led to some conditions for function (2) successfully executing not being met. But function (2) has no impact on the trigger at all, it is simply being triggered by the trigger.

Comment: Are you still experiencing the delay after the function has executed successfully?

Comment: hard to say, as the trigger has not been active the last couple of days ... I will monitor and  post a comment when I see it fire next time (hopefully on-time)

Comment: @tmwn6919 did you solve this issue?

Comment: OK, so fired yesterday with no issues, and I have not made any changes. I think this must have been a glitch somewhere, don't know where (though would take some comfort if I knew where). I think I'm going to close this issue for now. Thank you for the help!